# No suitable ARIMA model found

Tags: r, arima

When I invoke auto.arima inside a function in R I get the message Error in

```
auto.arima(ts(x, frequency = frequency(x)), xreg = xreg[1:length(x),  : 
  No suitable ARIMA model found
```

Here is the function.

```
arimax_Forecast=function(x,h,xreg){
  print(x)
  print(h)
  print(head(xreg))
  print(nrow(xreg))

  if (ncol(xreg)>=1){
  print("ARIMAX starting..")
Error occurs here-->  fitArima=auto.arima(ts(x,frequency = frequency(x)),xreg=xreg[1:length(x),])


  print("ARIMAX ending..")

  fcst=forecast(fitArima,xreg=xreg[(length(x)+1):(length(x)+h),])$mean

  } else {


    fitArima=auto.arima(ts(x,frequency = frequency(x)))

    fcst=forecast(fitArima,h=h)$mean


  }
  print("ARIMAX model")
  summary(fitArima)
  return(fcst)


}
```

Here is the result of the print statements at the beginning of the function.

```
Time Series:
Start = 1 
End = 3.64476386036961 
Frequency = 52.1785714285714 
  [1] 6487396 5874232 6367885 7750139 6587369 6846460 7319681 5630746 5655969 5709143
 [11] 5848434 5654539 5494925 5294804 5200583 5519086 5141921 5115428 4924138 5093168
 [21] 6021461 4548699 4762963 6303281 5520129 5842914 3591427 5061724 5358036 4831470
 [31] 4712211 5494639 6228857 5346616 5815208 5448833 6292768 6415695 6590986 5861075
 [41] 6420698 7271623 6227047 7390788 6828907 6976085 4792219 7001671 6805957 7715788
 [51] 6755935 5494691 6011299 6302709 6603400 7241145 6008982 6396488 6497909 6914611
 [61] 6747605 6637331 6112957 6644411 6324238 5772347 6024980 4910727 6751394 5886213
 [71] 6053883 5433128 6266485 5892834 5872764 5837265 5812827 6578622 3876096 5510503
 [81] 5720099 5879100 5822206 5734581 5913260 6912494 6022342 5383870 6194340 7008474
 [91] 6365029 6633334 6392968 7038605 6655945 6804469 6876568 7839269 4738264 7365312
[101] 8964034 6509020 5955178 4924796 5268856 5959803 5928851 6648663 6476169 5276701
[111] 5535896 6102519 6398450 5971538 6442206 5508491 5541464 5975188 5289838 5515657
[121] 5784894 6143415 4757634 5874963 6241383 4718858 5227543 5301905 5253445 5346498
[131] 4033132 5052134 5156338 4920428 5154340 4910591 6005701 6190418 5801289
[1] 5
     Shipping_Days     Price Orders_Min_1_Weeks PRIVATE LABEL Any Merch
[1,]             5 0.9477796            5565691                 1480685
[2,]             5 0.9132100            5559488                 1166134
[3,]             5 0.9187800            5905018                 1133441
[4,]             5 0.9294029            8529035                 1041792
[5,]             5 0.9574998            6957195                 1262740
[6,]             5 0.9275676            6549276                 1071959
[1] 144
[1] "ARIMAX starting.."
```

When `Orders_Min_1_Weeks` is removed the same code works. But I don't see any obvious issue with `Orders_Min_1_Weeks`. Can someone help me debug? Thank you.

Comment: This is not reproducible: what is `xreg`?  What library is `auto.arima` from?  (`forecast`, presumably, but maybe from something else?)

Comment: xreg is the matrix of regressors. From library forecast. I included the prints to give an idea of what xreg contains. xreg without Order_Min_1_Weeks works is accepted.

Comment: Clearly that's what `xreg` is--but since you don't provide its values, there's no way we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: The first few values are there in the question. Do they help at all?

Comment: Can we raise your problem using just the first six values?

Comment: I will have to attach more code than what is there for you to reproduce the problem. I was hoping that a look at the nature of values might help in the sense that it might be the case that if the values are too large they cause issues, or something similar. But that does not seem to be the case. I will delete the post in a while and re-post later if I deem suitable. Thank you.

Comment: @whuber Do you mind re-opening the question? I have an answer. The values in Order_Min_1_Weeks needed to be scaled by a factor of 1/100. They were too large.

Answer (score 2):

The values in Order_Min_1_Weeks needed to be scaled by a factor of 1/100. They were too large.

In particular, I needed to do the following since Order_Min_1_Weeks is the third regressor.

```
xreg[,3]=xreg[,3]/100
```

Comment: Sooner or later, somebody will get stuck while using auto.arima if they use large values for any of the regressors. And there will be no apparent solution because there is nothing fundamentally wrong with their inputs. What I have provided above will provide them with a ready solution if they come across this post. If you still think that this post is worth deleting, go ahead and delete.